# Bat file to get variable from text file then re-write text file

Tags: batch-file

I am having some difficulty with this bat file and I suspect it is because flag.txt is opened since it is required to get the variable for "flag".

I have tried to unload the variable but it still won't write to flag.txt I tested it with just echo commands, so I know my if/goto statements work properly.

Essentially, every time I run the bat file I would like it to change flag.txt to read 1, 2, or 3, depending on what is currently written. Thanks!

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in (flag.txt) do set flag=%%x


IF "%flag%"=="1" GOTO start1
IF "%flag%"=="2" GOTO start2
IF "%flag%"=="3" GOTO start3


echo Invalid flag: %flag%
goto :eof

:start1
echo 2 > flag.txt
exit

:start2
echo 1 > flag.txt
exit

:start3
echo 1 > flag.txt
exit
```

Comment: That's because you're not using any delimiters, and your code is specifically writing either `1<space>`, `2<space>`, or `3<space>` to the text file, _(please open `flag.txt` to check)_. The effect is that `"%flag%"` can never be equal to `"1"`, `"2"`, or `"3"`, it will always be either, `"1 "`, `"2 "`, or `"3 "`.

Answer (score 0):

Example of one possible alternative:

```bat
If Not Exist "flag.txt" (Echo ^1>"flag txt"
    GoTo :EOF)

Set "flag="
Set /P "flag="<"flag txt"

If %flag% Equ 3 GoTo Start3
If %flag% Equ 2 GoTo Start2
If %flag% Equ 1 GoTo Start1
Echo Invalid flag: %flag%
Pause
GoTo : EOF

:Start1
Echo ^2>"flag.txt"
GoTo :EOF

:Start2
Echo ^3>"flag.txt"
GoTo :EOF

:Start3
Echo ^1>"flag.txt"
GoTo :EOF
```

*The first two lines are optional, as I'm unsure of the rest of your task.*

Answer (score 0):

Same can be done with the following code:

```
@echo off
<flag.txt set /p flag=
set /a flag=flag%%3+1
>flag.txt echo %flag%
echo debug: %flag%
```

The second line reads the (first line of) the text file.
The third line alternates it as {1|2|3}, using the Modulo operator.
The fourth line writes the result back to the file (overwriting it).
Starting with the fifth line, you can insert any "payload".

If you don't like the errormessage at the very first run (missing `flag.txt`) (the following `set /a` does work regardless), you can use your line (slightly modified) `If Not Exist "flag.txt" (Echo 1)>"flag txt"` to create it.